# XML Creation using java translates CR in HTML Entity

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, html-entities

I've got a pretty serious problem with XML Creation using standard java objects, my code is as follows:

```
//Generate DOM
DOMSource source = this.generateDomDocument(params...);

//WRITE XML FILE
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

//Properties
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, STRING_FIELD_DTD);
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

//Convert and write to disk
transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(
                      new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), "UTF-8")));
```

Problem is, the transformer is transforming Carriage Returns in `&#13;` entities which I should not have in the resulting XML. This is an example, I have a result file with translations written in several different languages (that's why I use UTF-8) and they are all the same when they contain CarriageReturns in the text:

```
<content langID="EN">
                    <desc> Test string&#13;
do not copy.</desc>
```

To clear things up, this is what I expect in the XML:

```
<content langID="EN">
                    <desc> Test string
do not copy.</desc>
```

I looked up the issue on google and here too but there seems to be no solution or workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure, that I understand the problem correctly: The input data contains CRs and the XML output should a) not include them? or b) have simply a line break there? or c)... ?

Comment: The input data contains CRs and the XML output should simply have a line break and not something like &#13; then CRLF. I inspected the XML code with Notepad++ and this is what I found.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work I found two solutions to my own problem, they are more workarounds than real solutions:

**Solution 1**

Create a class that extends FilterOutputStream and implement the necessary methods to write every character on the final stream (a File in the case above) except for those unneeded, i.e. `&#13;`
To write to stream just add the filter:

```
 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(
                           new OutputStreamWriter(
                               new XMLFilterOutputStream(
                                   new FileOutputStream(filename)),"UTF-8"));
 transformer.transform(source, result);
```

**Solution 2**

When creating the DOM tree just escape the \r character (thus removing every Carriage Return from the original text):

```
String util = //original string data

Element desc = doc.createElement("desc");                   
Node text = doc.createTextNode((util!=null ? stringEscape(util).trim() : ""));
desc.appendChild(text);
externalElement.appendChild(desc);
```

And having the escaping method done this way:

```
private String stringEscape(String str){
    StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer(str);
    for(int i=0; i < st.length();i++){
        String s = st.substring(i,i+1);
        if("\r".equals(s)){
            st.replace(i,i+1,"");   
        }
    }
    return st.toString();
}
```

I know, it's *horrible*, but works.

The correct solution, AFAIK, should be accessing the HTMLEntities file in XALAN and modify that one, therefore forcing the transformer to omit some entities.

Comment: For `stringEscape` it's probably much faster something like `str.replaceAll("\r", "")`.